# 32 bit Java on 64 bit Windows 7 for running JBoss JSP Editor in Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jboss, java

I installed JBoss Tools on my Eclipse Juno. It worked, then when I click the tab design/view/ whatever it is except the source on my JSP window, It said that JBoss tool for JSP editor cannot run on my 64-bit Eclipse, JRE7, and Windows 7.

I've been browsing all over the place, some forums say you have to change your JRE to 32-bit. After that I installed JRE7 32-bit, restart and I tried to see the Java on Control Panel.

When I clicked Java tab on Control Panel, it said

> Couldn't open \lib\i386\jvm.cfg.

I tried to checked on CMD, I typed `java -version` then it displayed

> Unable to load native library: Can't load IA 32-bit.dll on AMD 64-bit platform.

Comment: *"It said that JBoss tool for JSP editor cannot run on my 64-bit Eclipse, JRE7, and Windows 7."* What's the **exact** error message? Who exactly is saying that?

Comment: I even now can't open my Eclipse because failed to load jvm.dll, but i can search it later. Here's my reference on changing to JRE7 32-bit. https://community.jboss.org/thread/164805 Please gimme enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to uninstall all Java instances, then start again.

Install 64-bit JDK first, set up your normal development tools to use it. Then install the 32-bit JDK but *don't install the public JRE*. Then configure a separate instance of Eclipse to use the 32-bit JDK. (I'd keep a separate, normal 64-bit Eclipse around, because 32-bit means you are limited to about 1.5Gb of heap for Java)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Artbristol, i did follow your advice. I threw away the JBoss tools and search another Web Development Kit plugins. Thanks all.